# Can't find a POST request while monitoring a website

Tags: python, python-requests

So I have been trying to create a bot with python that logs into my account on an online game called Tanki Online. I had mixed results when using selenium, so I decided to use requests rather than a web driver. And I'm a little stuck because when I started to monitor requests for the [game website](https://tankionline.com/play/) in the network tab I couldn't find any POST requests.

How does the game log accounts in if it doesn't use POST? And can I send a login request directly using python-requests?

Comment: Looks like it uses websockets to communicate with the server

Comment: Is it possible to send WebSockets with python?

Comment: Sure, there are packages like this for using websockets in Python https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/. As for authenticating with the server and sending messages in the correct format, you're going to have to reverse engineer all that

Comment: I found a POST request to:https://sentry.tankionline.com/api/28/store/?sentry_key that returned a 429 code when I tried too many times. Does this still mean that the website uses sockets for login?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.